# Get all nodes at a certain level JsTree Jquery

Tags: jquery, jstree

How do I use jquery to get all nodes at a certain level and perform an action for those nodes? I have a jstree that I fill with json data so adding my own id for each node level isn't possible.

For example, I want to get all nodes at level 3:

```
Root
    A1
      1
      2
      3
```

The numbers 1, 2, and 3 would be the level 3 nodes. I would like to change the icons for just the level 3 nodes. Right now I can change all the nodes icons with the following:

```
a>.jstree-icon
        {
            background-image: url("content/img/usersmallclipart.png")!important;
            background-position: 0!important;

        }
```

I would like to use jquery to get all the nodes at level 3 and use the .css() to change the icons if a certain context is met (which is why I need to use jquery rather than simply going deeper with my css style).

So pseudo code would be as follows:

1. Get all nodes at level 3
2. If a node has children - change it's icon, else - do nothing

How can I do this?
Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the treeview loads you can use jQuery to iterate through each node and apply your css depending on the level of the node. For example, you may try the following once jstree loads the tree view:

```
$("#myTree").bind('ready.jstree', function (event, data) {
    var $tree = $(this);
    $($tree.jstree().get_json($tree, {
        flat: true
    })).each(function () {
        // Get the level of the node
        var level = $("#myTree").jstree().get_node(this.id).parents.length;
        var node;
        if (level == 3) {
            // node = ... apply desired css to the node here if it has children.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: var node = this;

Comment: I left the **node** declared on purpose, leaving it for the user to decide. Depending on the implementation, **this** may not be sufficient. In my case, I use **$("#myTree").jstree().get_node(this.id);**

Answer (score 0):

Use the wildcard selector of css `*`

```
.root *  { color: blue } /* first level */
.root * *  { color: red } /* second level */
.root * * * { color: yellow } /* third level */
.root * * * * { color: green } /* fourth level */
```

Comment: Thank you but I think I should have been more specific, Root was just my example name of a first level node. In my jstree I actually have many first level nodes with different names. And I need to use jquery because the icon should only change if a certain condition is met.

Comment: Is the same on jquery $("* * * *").css({"background-color":"blue"});

Comment: Yes, I've been trying that many different ways but it just doesn't color the 4th level. Any other suggestions?